# Java applet get document cookies?

Tags: java, cookies, applet

And for the life of me I can't figure out why I can't access the document's cookies for the applet's origin. Same page, same IP address. When I actually make the connection via Java, I see the cookies being sent (in wireshark), so I know they're there.

Does anyone have any alternate ways to try to access the document cookies from Java? I've scoured around the internet, and can't seem to find anything that might work besides the `getRequestProperty()` method!

I have the following applet code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import netscape.javascript.*;

public class test extends Applet {
    public void init() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.0.5/java/test.html");            
        String inputLine;
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        System.out.print("Cookies:\n");
        String m = conn.getRequestProperty("Cookie");
        // Returns null :-/
        System.out.println(m);

        // Read page content => works fine... (sends cookie)
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        //while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        //    System.out.println(inputLine);
        //in.close();        
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Error :(");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    String alert = "alert(document.cookie);";
    JSObject win = (JSObject) JSObject.getWindow(this);
    win.eval(alert);
    }
}
```

Also is there any way to get the `JSObject` window to my `URLConnection`? Otherwise it sets me in the context of the current applet window...

Comment: is the cookie header name "Set-Cookie:" not sure ...

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the browser is putting a wrapper around the Java connection, the wrapper is handling the cookies, so the Java connection doesn't see them?  Try printing out all of the request properties you *do* get (via `getRequestProperties()`), that might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Hrm, it doesn't seem to return anything to me! I wonder why that is...

Comment: Do the cookies have `HttpOnly` set on them? That will keep Java from getting at them in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpURLConnection.getRequestProperty
```

only returns what you add to it via the addRequestProperty to be sent when the connection is made via connect.  The response headers may contain Cookie or Set-Cookie headers which can give you some clue about the cookies from the server.

To get cookies for your Applet's page:

1. 1.define a javascript function such as the following - this should be part of the page containing your applet.

   ```
   function getDocumentCookies() 
   {
     return document.cookie;
   }
   ```
2. se jsobject to invoke, for example:

   ```
   private String getDocumentCookies()
   {
     JSObject window = (JSObject)JSObject.getWindow(this);
     return window.call ("getDocumentCookies", new String[0]);
   }
   ```